# Filtering a Url via Regex

Tags: regex, nutch

Given these seed urls:

```
http://greenbook.americansalon.com/cat/Haircolor.htm
http://greenbook.americansalon.com/cat/Cosmetics.htm
http://greenbook.americansalon.com/cat/Shampoos-and-Conditioners.htm
```

I'd like to  crawl (via Nutch 1.4) through urls that match only the following rules:

- Only Categories that are "Haircolor", "Cosmetics" and "Shampoos-and-Conditioners" (as seed urls). I.e. nothing else can come in url after `http://greenbook.americansalon.com/cat/` .
- Any  `http://greenbook.americansalon.com/company/...` is accptable.
- Any site other than "greenbook.americansalon" is acceptable.

Mentioning the seed urls is not a guarantee, of course, since it's possible to get to other categories from them.

I want a regex negating:

```
http\:\/\/greenbook\.americansalon\.com\/([leaf|cat]+\/[^Haircolor|Cosmetics|Shampoos].*)
```

and combining

```
http\:\/\/greenbook.americansalon.com\/company\/.*
```

and any other site ( `.+` ) -  (For example - `http://www.spilo.com/index.asp` should also be caught).

In other words - give me all the urls (including other domains than "greenbook.americansalon") that follow the rules I mentioned.

Comment: Why you used a negated character class?

Comment: Maybe the edited and more clarified question demonstrates the need of negation. 
Besides, Nutch allows me to filter which Regex not to match and match everything other than it (so I can play with it and double negate when needed/more comfortable).

Comment: On the other hand, I think:

`+http\:\/\/greenbook\.americansalon\.com\/(?:(leaf|cat)\/(?:Haircolor|Cosmetics|Shampoos)\b|company\b).*

-.+ `

should work, as a far as it comes to Nutch (not including everything else).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
http\:\/\/greenbook\.americansalon\.com\/(?:(leaf|cat)\/(?:Haircolor|Cosmetics|Shampoos)\b|company\b).*
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/wP7pR2/8)

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches valid URLs according to your rules:

```
http((\:\/\/greenbook\.americansalon\.com\/(((leaf|cat)\/(Haircolor|Cosmetics|Shampoos))|company\b).*)|(s?\:\/\/(?!greenbook\.americansalon\.com).*))
```

[**Online demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mE0gG2/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want seperate regex. Then the first one can be:

```
http\:\/\/greenbook\.americansalon\.com\/leaf|cat\/(?=Haircolor|Cosmetics|Shampoos).*
```

The other two look fine.